# How to Push a clear or alpha UIViewCotroller

Tags: ios, controller, push

A button in UIViewController VC1，from this button，we need push(not present) a UIViewController VC2，and VC2's backgroundColor is clearColor or with alpha.

Maybe somepeople will answer me：just setBackgroundColor [UIColor clearColor],if this,the VC2 will be clear or with alpha when it pushing,but after animation complete,it's backgroundColor will be black or white strangely，that's my doubt.I just want VC2 above on VC1，and from VC1 i can see VC1，and just push not present!

Comment: What have you tried, in what way is that not working and what exactly is the desired result? The answer to your actual question is just to set the views backgroundcolor and push it! but i guess that is not what you want - you need to be more specific.

Comment: View controllers don't have background colors; views do.  The difference is important.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the below code :

```
[viewController2.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Pushing a new view controller will cause the first view controller's view to be removed from display. Setting the background color of the second view controller will not help.

You will likely need to manage the overlay as a subview to the first view controller's view.

Answer (score 0):

"Presenting" a view controller means to display one view controller over another. "Pushing" a view controller means to replace one view controller with another. If you want to keep the other view controller around, you must present the new one, not push it.

If by "push" you mean "slide in from the right," then you really mean you want to present it with a custom transition. This is usually done with a `UIPresentationController` in iOS 8. In iOS 7, you can do it slightly more by hand using a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` to provide the animation you want.

You should take a look at [Custom UIViewController Transitions](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/) by Ash Furrow for a nice introduction to the iOS 7 way. The iOS 8 is nicely covered (in Swift) by ["Custom presentations using UIPresentationController in Swift"](http://zappdesigntemplates.com/custom-presentations-using-uipresentationcontroller-swift/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok,ultimate solution:
From VC1 push to VC2,VC1 just do this:

step1,
    [VC1 addChildViewController:VC2];
    [VC1.view addSubview:VC2.view];
    [VC1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
setp2,
    VC2 setBackgroundColor clearColor or alpha.